# name of the uploaded file to be entered in input in front of it

Tags: javascript

I have a table whose rows are added automatically.

In the last column of this table there is an input for uploading the file and I want the name of the uploaded file to be entered in input in front of each of the upload buttons.

Since the ID of each input is the same, how should I do this?

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" id="audio-input" onchange="document.querySelector(&quot;#sa&quot;).value=this.files[0].name">
    <input id="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="audio-input" onchange="document.querySelector(&quot;#sa&quot;).value=this.files[0].name">
    <input id="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="audio-input" onchange="document.querySelector(&quot;#sa&quot;).value=this.files[0].name">
    <input id="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="audio-input" onchange="document.querySelector(&quot;#sa&quot;).value=this.files[0].name">
    <input id="sa">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this script for you, but remember never use ID multiple times use classes.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".sa");
const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".audio-input");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function change(el){
for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
if(el.parentElement == divs[i]){
inputs[i].value = el.files[0].name;
}
}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" class="audio-input" onchange="change(this)">
    <input class="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" class="audio-input" onchange="change(this)">
    <input class="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" class="audio-input" onchange="change(this)">
    <input class="sa">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="file" class="audio-input" onchange="change(this)">
    <input class="sa">
</div>
```

Edit: It also works with IDs, but its bad (please use classes) look here: https://codepen.io/filip769/pen/RwopVad?editors=1010